# Debian/Mint/Raspbian/Ubuntu - How to force SLAAC EUI64 IPv6 autoconfiguration?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, linux-mint, ipv6, raspbian

I have a static IPv6 /62 prefix and I use radvd on my router (running Debian) to advertise a /64 from within it to my entire network.  Other than my router (which is ::1), I let EUI64 set the suffix based on the MAC address (i.e. matching the suffix of the automatic fe80:: address).

Most Linuxes are migrating to masking this for privacy reasons.  I am really not concerned about the privacy implications, and further, want a perfectly predictable IPv6 address for services such as sshd.

In theory, this should be easy to configure.  For example, on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, I've added to the /etc/sysctl.conf file:

> ###################################################################
>
> # Enable IPv6 EUI64
>
> #
>
> net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr=0
>
> net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr=0
>
> net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr=0

Alas, nothing changes.  (The last line was a last-ditch attempt; the previous two lines really ought to work alone.)

Something in these OSes is preventing EUI64 from working.  What is it, and how do I enable it?

This particular machine is *not* running NetworkManager, but some of them are.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are confusing two different address types:

- temporary addresses generated according to RFC 4941 "Privacy extensions",
- permanent addresses generated according to RFC 7217 "Opaque interface identifiers".

The former are always generated *in addition to* the default address and do not replace it, so certainly not what you have in mind.

The latter do replace the default EUI64-based address, but they are *not temporary* and have nothing to do with the `use_tempaddr` knob. Instead you need to change the primary address generation mode:

- If SLAAC is performed by the kernel, change this sysctl:

  ```
  net.ipv6.conf.default.addr_gen_mode = 0
  net.ipv6.conf.eth0.addr_gen_mode = 0
  ```

  (Looking at source code, it doesn't seem like `all.addr_gen_mode` is implemented.)
- If SLAAC is performed by *dhcpcd*, use this `dhcpcd.conf` option:

  ```
  slaac hwaddr
  ```
- If SLAAC is performed by NetworkManager:

  ```
  nmcli con modify "Connection name" ipv6.addr-gen-mode eui64
  ```

Comment: Thank you; I'll give this a try.  I don't absolutely require that my systems use the default EUI64 addresses, although I prefer it since they're predictable.  A permanent IPv6 suffix of some other sort would also be suitable.  The address I have now seems to be temporary 2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 blahblah::4d6a:b4b0:7b0d:41af/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic

Comment: The secret for this situation was "slaac hwaddr" in /etc/dhcpcd.conf.  Thank you.

Comment: No, if it doesn't say _the exact word_ `temporary`, then you're still looking at a permanent address, and it's fine to use it in DNS and elsewhere. (It is based on hashing the network prefix and a secret key... uh, in dhcpcd's case probably /etc/dhcpd.duid?)

Comment: Don't be confused by `mngtmpaddr` which has a nearly-opposite meaning. (It tells the kernel "if use_tempaddr is active, please manage temporary addresses _based on_ this address".)

Comment: How do I know which one is doing the SLAAC?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi documentation has a section called [Configuring Networking](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#configuring-networking), which tells you where to set these options. My RPi is a server connected via Ethernet cable, so currently it tells me I need to configure `dhcpcd`.

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS based on Debian Bookworm is now using Network Manager instead of `dhcpcd`. See [reference](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/1f906471e79ab889685e17e0ef8c787b8492c7c5/documentation/asciidoc/computers/configuration/configuring-networking.adoc).